# Laravel PHPUnit with bitbucket-pipelines.yml file. Vendor related files not found issue

Tags: php, laravel, bitbucket

I have laravel 5.3 project on bitbucket. I have all folders integrated with bitbucket except auto generated folders like Vendor folder. And I am trying to run Unit test with bitbucket-pipelines.yml.

But It is showing error

> "PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory"

on vendor files like `/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php` as I don't have vendor folder on bitbucket.

Is there any way to run `PHPunit` without vendor folder?

I have also tries `composer update` command before `PHPUnit` in `.yml` file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got solution. We simply do this by creating docker image. I have done this by writing these commands in .yml file

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
composer -V
php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');" 
composer install
php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `composer install -o --no-suggest` to your bitbucket-pipelines.yml, so that it will get all the dependencies before run unit tests.

Comment: Can you please look at this and tell me what could be the issue http://prntscr.com/gvkc6y

Comment: Can  you paste your complete bitbucket-pipelines.yml here ?

Comment: As per the screenshot, the issue is with the mysql connection which you use when running unit testing. I would suggest you to use sqlite as the db on unit testing. You can define a `.env.testing` to override database when running unit tests.

Comment: Here is my .yml file

    image: php:7-fpm

pipelines:
 branches:
  cba-sit:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -qy git curl libmcrypt-dev mysql-client
          - docker-php-ext-install mcrypt && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer -V
          - php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');" 
          - composer install
          - vendor/bin/phpunit